# Can't connect to nodejs application on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

iam trying to connect php application with another nodejs application on heroku using socket.io

code using for connection on client (php app)

```
<script src="http://mynodeapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js/"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var reguser_socket = io.connect('http://mynodeapp.herokuapp.com');   
console.log("connected");
<script>
```

code using on server (nodejs app)

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
var app = http.createServer(handler).listen(port);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.configure(function(){
io.set('log level', 1);
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
io.set("polling duration", 10);
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 console.log("client has connection established "); 
});
```

But while runnig this i get

```
GET http://mynodeapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/?t=1384779309815
(Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Web Sockets on Heroku, you need to run:

`heroku labs:enable websockets`

because it is only in public beta.

See here for a general overview on how to use it with Heroku:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

Comment: @mohamed.alsum where is your definition of the handler function?

Answer (score 0):

This section of code works fine my connection was interrupted because i have another part of code cause this problem